# clip-path not being rendered

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to get an image to overlay a video, but clip that image so it doesn't go past the edges of the video frame.  The clip-path I'm using does not seem to be working.

```
.clipped {  

  position: absolute; 
  clip-path: rectangle(0, 792, 480, 0);
}
<div style="position: relative;">

  <!-- Background wrapper: -->
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <!-- All background content goes here... -->
    <video style="cursor: crosshair" width="792" height="480" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
  <source src="http://cdn.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/post_files/uotw16.1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>

  <!-- Content wrapper; all original content goes inside of this div: -->
  <div style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
    <!-- Begin content block -->

   <img class="clipped" src="http://ultrasoundoftheweek.com/uploader/grid_inside.png" astyle="width:1300px;height:1300px">
    <!-- End content block -->
  </div>

</div>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wgjb1Lm/3/)

Comment: The image doesn't exceed the axes. Can you add some details? (maybe a screen capture to emphasize the problem)

Comment: the image has a lot of transparency and white, so it is hard to see that it extends to the whole size 1300x1300: http://www.ultrasoundoftheweek.com/uploader/grid_inside.png

Comment: Could be because of `clip-path: rectangle(0, 792, 480, 0);` It should read `rect` NOT `rectangle`.